# Query to get Object_ID and Dimension_Name from DMV

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dmv

I am looking for a DMV query which contain `Dimension_Name` and `Object_ID` together.

I have `System.mdschema_dimensions` to get the Dimension Unique name and `System.discover_object_activity` to get the Object_ID.

They showed together in the dimension properties and I'm interested if there's any DMV which shows them together.